# xgettext - extract translatable strings and update .pot

Tags: c++, c, gettext, xgettext

I have inherited a sample.pot file. Now, I have added new messages in a1.c and a2.cpp. Is it possible for me to use xgettext and output the contents to same sample.pot instead of creating a new one? Eg:-

```
xgettext -d sample -s -o sample.pot a1.c
xgettext -d sample -s -o sample.pot a2.cpp
```

Is this preferred way to go in order to update the template such that old messages are also preserved? The other question is how do we distinguish translatable strings from normal strings in source code. I assume xgettext will pull all strings from mentioned source code file.

It would be great if anybody can share the correct approach..Thanks

Comment: see Peter Brett answer : that the way !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the `-j`, `--join-existing` option ("join messages with existing file") not do what you need?

Note that you can specify more than one input file on the command line.

```
xgettext -d sample -s -j -o sample.pot a1.c a2.cpp
```

Comment: +1: that the way to do it : use -j and ${list_of_files_to_i18nize}

Comment: Thanks @Peter and @neuro..That was just th eflag I was looking for. Apparently, I confused it with merge option.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this is:

```
xgettext -o sample.pot -s a1.c a2.cpp sample.pot
```

You don't need `-j`, `--join-existing` because xgettext accepts `.po` and `.pot` files as regular input files.

The option `-j`, `--join-existing` is rarely useful.  In conjunction with `-D`, `--directory` it has the effect that the output file `sample.pot` used as an input file is *not* searched in the list of directories.  If you use `-l c`, `--language=c` you need `-j`, `--join-existing` because `sample.pot` would otherwise be parsed as a C/C++ source file.

Besides, `-o sample.pot`, `--output=sample.pot` has exactly the same effect as `-d sample`, `--default-domain=sample`.  You can safely omit one of them.